# How to convert string to Boolean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, code-behind

I have a public property returned from my code-behind class to `aspx` page:

```
window.MyWIndow.IsFull = '<%=this.IsFull%>';
```

In code-behind it is defined this way:

```
public bool IsFull
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Now, when I use it in my javascript file, I have the following code:

```
var isShow = myself.IsFull;
```

This way `isShow` is either `'True'` or `'False'`

I need to convert it on the page level, so `isShow` is `boolean` instead of `string`.

So I can write the `if else` logic

How can I do it?

Comment: *"tried different things"* ... always show what you tried

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse('true');`

```
JSON.parse(isShow.toLowerCase());
```

Try the example below.

```js
var result = ['True', 'False']

var isShow = result[Math.round(Math.random())];

console.log(JSON.parse(isShow.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: `toLowerCase` is a function ...also check spelling

Answer (score 3):

If you know it's always going to return the string True and False, you could just use;

```
window.MyWindow.IsFull = '<%=this.IsFull%>' === "True";
```

Comment: What if some browser returns "true" instead of "True"?

Comment: @gene - that's not up to the browser ... `<%=this.IsFull%>` will be "True" or "False" - nothing else

Comment: This this would assume you meant False. It's not the browser that returns this - it's his backend. He stated in the question very clearly that he knew it was going to return `True` or `False`. If he can't depend on that, then he may need to do some string manipulation.

Comment: @shadow - that was the OP asking!!

Comment: Huh, so it was. :P If your isFull function is returning a legit boolean, then it won't change case on you. But to be safe, you could always either use Jaramoda's idea, or `'<%=this.IsFull%>'.toLowerCase() === 'true';`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method is

```
window.MyWIndow.IsFull = <%=this.IsFull.ToString().ToLower()%>;
```

Note, no quotes

Answer (score -1):

wrong answer is wrong...

> A couple of options.  You can use the built in `Boolean` [object
>   wrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)
>   like this:
>
> ```
> var string = myself.IsFull
> var isShow = new Boolean(string.toLowercase);
> ```
>
> or use the logical
>   [NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!))
>   operator twice like this:
>
> ```
> var string = myself.IsFull
> var isShow = !(!string.toLowercase);
> ```
>
> edit: but why???? [![enter image description here][1]][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/359zg.png

Comment: wont work if `myself.IsFull` is a **string** - 'True' or 'False' as stated in the question

Comment: fiiiiixed it :)

Comment: toLowerCase is a function - and `new Boolean('false')` is still true, as is `!(!'false')` - I suggest when you test your code, test that all possible inputs produce the desired output - clearly you're testing true only! - a non-empty string will always be truthy

Comment: because toLowercase is `undefined` - or falsey, any string given that code would result in false ... toLowerCase, on the other hand, is a function, using toLowerCase would result in any string becoming `true` - used as a function, toLowerCase() would result in any non-empty string being true, and empty string being false